# How to count the number of source packages

Tags: package-management

I'm comparing Ubuntu to other distributions for a number of factors, and for one factor I need the number of source packages, which is probably a better indicator than the total number of packages a distribution has.

It looks like I could use `apt-cache dumpavail` and from each section get the package name or the source name, if there is one, then get a unique count from that.  But, is there an easier, faster way?

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `apt-cache stats`?

Comment: I looked at `apt-cache stats`, but I didn't see anything that looked like the count of source packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `grep` the number of `Package:` lines in the files whose names end in `_Sources` in the directory `/var/lib/apt/lists/`:

```
grep '^Package: ' /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Sources | wc -l
```

On my Ubuntu 11.10 machine I get the number 17150.

Comment: Since I have a ppa that copies some packages from Ubuntu, I ended up using this: `grep -h '^Package: ' /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Sources | sort -u | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can dump the output to a text file and then using gedit , find the number of lines , the number  of lines represent the number of packages. ( I assume that 1 package takes 1 line)